# Quartus 18 IP Error

Tags: quartus

I am currently trying to use Quartus 18.0 IP Catalog suggestions to import a UART RS-232 block to set up this serial interface.
I have set the clock domain and the output pin (using datasheet to DE0-CV board) but when I try to finish the UART setup by pressing "Generate HDL..." I get this error:

Error: rs232_0: The input clock frequency must be known at generation time.

How can I tell Quartus my clock frequency so that it could generate my UART module without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a clock source for the UART component you want to create.

This can be done as follow:

- In your *IP Parameter editor* go under `Edit > Add...`
- In the Add instance windows, search for `Clock` and select "`Clock Source`" under "`Clocks; PLLs and Resets`"
- Add the Clock and update the default frequency and clock Finish
- Go to `View > Connections` in *IP Parameter editor*
- Tick the boxes to connect the clocks together
- Generate and finish should stop giving you an error.

Qsys (under `Tools > Platform Designer`) maybe easier for the connections, maybe you can also have a look at it.